# How to delete new Module I created accidentally in Android Studio?Git couldn't recover it status

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I add new module in Android Studio accidentally.

[image]

So let left project file not normal.
[image]

How to delete new Module I created accidentally?
Git couldn't recover it status.

Comment: try using local history: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone help me solve this problem.
Since I add Module from Intellij Idea.So couldn't delete this new module from Android Studio. Must use Intellij Idea to delete module from project structure
Module -